# Error Invalid DOUBLE

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I get "invalid Double "" " when i try to show some markers on a map, i have stored in a db latitude and longitude and using these information i try to display markers on a map.

i'm following this tutorial: http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-google-map-marker-php-mysql.html

I really hope someone can point me to the right direction

Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private GoogleMap googleMap;

private Double campo_latitud = 0.00;
private Double campo_longitud = 0.00;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> location = null;
    String url = "http://www.thaicreate.com/android/getLatLon.php"";


    try {

        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getHttpGet(url));
        location = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        HashMap<String, String> map;

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){

            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", c.getString("id"));
            map.put("campo_latitud", c.getString("campo_latitud"));
            map.put("campo_longitud", c.getString("campo_longitud"));
            map.put("campo_categoria", c.getString("campo_categoria"));
            location.add(map);

            System.out.println("campo_latitud");

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    campo_latitud = Double.parseDouble(location.get(0).get("campo_latitud").toString());
    System.out.println("campo_latitud");
    campo_longitud = Double.parseDouble(location.get(0).get("campo_longitud").toString());
    LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(campo_latitud, campo_longitud);
    googleMap.setMapType(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 17));

    for (int i = 0; i < location.size(); i++) {
        campo_latitud = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("Latitude").toString());
        campo_longitud = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("Longitude").toString());
        String name = location.get(i).get("LocationName").toString();
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(campo_latitud, campo_longitud)).title(name);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    }
}


public static String getHttpGet(String url) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);

        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode == 200) { // Download OK

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            InputStream content = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                str.append(line);
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("Log", "Failed to download result..");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str.toString();
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
10-17 23:25:18.650 27527-27527/com.example.dell.mapamarcadoresoct17 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.dell.mapamarcadoresoct17, PID: 27527
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dell.mapamarcadoresoct17/com.example.dell.mapamarcadoresoct17.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                                                                                      at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                                                      at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
                                                                                      at com.example.dell.mapamarcadoresoct17.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

NEW LOGCAT:

```
10-18 00:26:04.290 9108-9108/com.example.dell.mapamarcadoresoct17 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.dell.mapamarcadoresoct17, PID: 9108
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dell.mapamarcadoresoct17/com.example.dell.mapamarcadoresoct17.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.dell.mapamarcadoresoct17.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:104)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Please provide your complete code

Comment: Sure @Tasneem i'll update it

Comment: Done @Tasneem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""` .

**Sample**

```
String str = "";
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(str)){
    double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
}
```

Try this in your code .

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(location.get(i).get("Latitude").toString()) &&!TextUtils.isEmpty(location.get(i).get("Longitude").toString())){
        campo_latitud = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("Latitude").toString());
        campo_longitud = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("Longitude").toString());
}
```

Comment: Adding this line i got a different logcat

Comment: Show it in your code .

Comment: done my friend!

Comment: You can accept my answer.

Comment: Sure, and do you have an idea why it's receiving a null value, i mean why it seems to not be retrieving from the php file

Comment: You should parse JSON inside method and also can use `postman` to try it first .

Comment: Thanks man so much, it's working now!!

Comment: Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

your Logs say everything...

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

it means while using `parseDouble()` you are passing null value to this method.